fixing generic-6.8.0.41 boot LUKS unlock
couple of days ago i run the release upgrade on my 22.04 mate desktop to 24.04.1 and first reboot went well, the next day i wasn't able to unlock machine with error message that vg-ubuntu--mate could not be found. Tried boot-repair with no luck.
Only way to unlock right now is choosing 6.8.0.40 kernel.
Learned that waiting for .1 is not enough time passed plus to newer do -d upgrades, had a lapse of judgement when i did the -d upgrade, that's on me.
Anyways, which options next to full reinstall which i really want to avoid remain at this moment?
